# How does the elf level 2 magic ability work in Ultra Tiny Epic Kingdoms?

Tags: tiny-epic-kingdoms

When elves reach the 2nd level of their magic book, they gain this ability:

> If you pay for war only using [mana], -1 war cost.

However, mana always counts as 2 for war:

> Win or lose, both players must pay their war cost. To pay your war cost, subtract any war cost abilities and then pay the remaining value with resources at the rate noted on the resource track: Mana is worth 2,...

I have 2 questions:

1. In multiplayer games, does this mean I have to choose an odd number war value to take advantage of this ability? I.e. odd -1 is even, then I can pay purely in mana
2. In solo play, the war cost is set to either the number of armies that the dummy player has, or this number times 2 (depending whether it is day or night). Does this mean the ability is only valid for odd numbered war values?

Answer (score 2):

A similar post for the 1st edition rules is on [boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1395792/elves-level-2). The designer says:

> Actually, it's not ... The "+1 War Power" is a resource discount (you can bid 7 but only pay 6). This is much clearer in 2nd edition.

This implies that you can dial an odd number and pay the even number cost.

For the solo play, this only useful if the war cost is odd.

Comment: Turns out 2nd edition has the exact same text for the ability. So much for being clearer.